# MATLAB matching columns/tables

Tags: matlab, for-loop, math, matching, matlab-coder

I have two tables:

Table 1 has two columns called WP_1 and WP_2.

Table 2 has three columns called WP1, WP2 and WC.

For every pair (row) of WP_1 and WP_2 I want to check if they are within any pair (row) of WP1 and WP2.

If they are within a certain pair of WP1 and WP2, I want to take the value (0 or 1) of WC of that specific pair and print it to a new column in table1 in the same row --> table1.WC

If a pair of WP_1 and WP_2 does not fit any pair of WP1 and WP2 I want to print the value '2' in that specific line of table1.WC.

Here is an example of how I want it to look like:

[what table1.Wc should look like after running the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCG6k.png)

Explanation:

WP_1 and WP_2 in row 1 are [0,0] and fit within WP1 and WP2 in row1 [0,145] --> therefor WC in table 1 for that row is equal to WC in table2

WP_1 and WP_2 in row 2 are [0,5] and fit within WP1 and WP2 in row1 [0,145] --> therefor WC in table 1 for that row is equal to WC in table2
....

WP_1 and WP_2 in row 4 are [115,219] and DON'T fit within any pair of WP1 and WP2 in any row --> therefor WC in table 1 for that row is 2

WP_1 and WP_2 in row 5 are [219,262] and fit within WP1 and WP2 in row3 [169,1693] --> therefor WC in table 1 for that row is equal to WC in table2

My Code so far:

```
for n = 1:height(table1)
    for m = 1:height(table2)
    if table1.WP_1(n) >= table2.WP1(m) &...
        table1.WP_2(n) <= table2.WP2(m)
        table1.WC(n) = table2.WC(m);
    else table1.WC(n) = 2;
    end
    end
end
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about the exact problem that you are facing? The way your problem is presented is convoluted and hard to follow. You could create a reduced version of your data set that represents what you are trying to work with. Otherwise, it will be hard to help you. Have you tried debugging your code and see the status of your variables and indices?

Comment: Thank you for your comment - I updated my data and restructured my question. Any help is very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I still find the edited explanation too hard to understand. I suggest changing the example data to a *toy problem*, with the simplest sets of numbers that still illustrates all the aspects of the problem. The second set of example doesn't map with the first two tables, and I find that confusing. Show a clear input-output of what you actually want, and the different things you need to do to achieve that. I also strongly suggest *writing your own algorithm out on paper to explain to yourself*; it usually helps to see all the steps laid out in front of you.

Comment: thanks for your comment - I edited everything, so it should be more clear now. Thanks for reading!

Comment: `table2.WP1(1:m)` gives you all the columns of `WP1` from 1 to m, but your explanation talks about comparing rows.  Are `table1` and `table2` the same length?  And do you always want to compare just the rows?  If so, you only need one loop.  If you want to search all rows of `table2` for any instance of `table1`, you again only need 1 loop.  I'd suggest looking at `ismember` and `ismember(A,B,'rows')`.

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks for your comment. The tables don't have the same size. As they don't have the same size I want to check for every pair(row) of WP_1 & WP_2 in table1 if they are WITHIN ANY pair(row) of WP1 & WP2 in table 2. I had a look at ismember, but ismember only checks if they are the exact value, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple brute force approach that uses `find` to get the index of the first match where the value in the rows are within the ranges of the second table.  If  table2.WP2(n) == table2.WP1(n+1) always, there are some shortcuts that can be used.

```
% Preallocate the output as not found
table1.WC = ones(length(table1.WP_1),1) * 2;
for i = 1:length(table1.WP_1)
    idx = find(and(table1.WP_1(i) >= table2.WP1, table1.WP_2(i) <= table2.WP2), 1, 'first');
    if ~isempty(idx)
        table1.WC(i) = table2.WC(idx);
    end
end
```

You can replace the `and(...,...)` with `&` to make it shorter as well.  I like the readability of `and`.